# On Google Sites, is it possible to directly provide my own pages, stylesheets etc without going thru the creating process?

Tags: google-apps, google-sites

Now I have to pick a template and jump thru bunch of loops to create a page that I don't like. So we wonder if it's possible to just drop a few web pages and the css that we created on our own as our web site on Google Apps, doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, that is not possible. I made a google site for a client last year, and it takes a lot of hoops to go through for customization. You can do quite a bit, it might not be readily noticeable. I found googling the things I wanted to do tended to yield the quickest results.